# Filter dataframe for columns that contain data in R using tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, across

I am trying to make a simple line of code to detect where there are incorrect entries in a dataframe.
Consider the following example:

```
author   val1   val2   val3   val4
A         1      B      1      NA
A         NA     NA     NA     NA
NA        2      B      NA     B
NA        NA     NA     NA     B
NA        NA     NA     NA     NA
A         2      A      NA     B
```

A row always needs to have the author filled in, but this is sometimes forgotten. Also, sometimes row 2 has the author filled in, but by accident the rest of the data is entered on row 3.

What i want is to filter for rows that have `NA` for author and after that filter for any data entrie in whatever column. So my expected output for the above example would be:

```
author   val1   val2   val3   val4
NA        2      B      NA     B
NA        NA     NA     NA     B
```

Filtering for the rows with NA for author is easy, but i cant figure out what to do next. My code so far:

```
 df %>%
  filter(
    is.na(author)
    ) %>%  
  filter(
    across(
      .cols = everything(),
      .fns = ~ !is.na(.x)
    )
  )
```

I have the feeling i am pretty close, but after a few hours of trying and looking on stack my code still returns empty dataframes to me. I would prefer a solution in tidyverse syntax, but any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code is not very efficient but it seems to work.

```
library(stringr)
library(rebus)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

df <- tibble(author = c('A', 'A', NA, NA, NA, 'A'),
             val1   = c(1, NA, 2, NA, NA, 2),
             val2   = c('B', NA, 'B', NA, NA, 'A'),
             val3   = c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA , NA),
             val4   = c(NA, NA, 'B', 'B', NA, 'B'))

df_na <- filter(df, is.na(author)) 

#map and str_which will cover each column

index <- map(df_na,~ str_which(.x, pattern = rebus::or(ANY_CHAR, DGT))) %>% 
    keep(~ length(.x) != 0) %>% #filter any columns that are all NA
    unlist() %>%
    unique()

df_na %>% extract(index, )
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! 
When using the last line, with the extract function, i get this error returned:  

Error: Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
x Subscript `var` has size 2 but must be size 1.

I understand only half of the code, so it is difficult for me to tackle the error unfortunately.

Comment: The last line es equivalent to: df_na[index, ]

Comment: Thanks, i got it working! My own dataset was somehwat more complex so the code needed to be adjusted. Works perfectly now, thanks a lot!